# Converting an xlsx file to a dictionary in Python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to import a dataframe from an xlsx file to Python and then convert this dataframe to a dictionary. This is how my Excel file looks like:

```
  A B
1 a b
2 c d
```

where A and B are names of columns and 1 and 2 are names of rows.

I want to convert the data frame to a dictionary in python, using pandas. My code is pretty simple:

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = pd.read_excel(‘.\inflation.xlsx’, sheet_name = ‘Sheet2’, index_col=0).to_dict()
print(my_dict)
```

What I want to get is:

```
 {‘a’:’b’, ‘c’:’d’}
```

But what I get is:

```
{‘b’:{‘c’:’d’}}
```

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what is requested:

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.read_excel(‘.\inflation.xlsx’, sheet_name = ‘Sheet2’,index_col=0,header=None).transpose().to_dict('records')[0]
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

The [to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) function takes an `orient` parameter which specifies how the data will be manipulated. There are other options if you have more rows.

Comment: @besola Happy to help (with an assist from @BigBen). Please tick it as the accepted answer, to guide others.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = pd.read_excel(‘.\inflation.xlsx’, sheet_name = ‘Sheet2’,header = 0 index_col=None).to_dict('records')
print(my_dict)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).